# How to properly change an `Observable` that results in view changes in a parent component?

Tags: angular

I have a component that changes a value in an application-global service and am sometimes seeing `Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'` messages. I know that these can be silenced by enabling production mode, but I would prefer to understand how to do this properly.

**tl;dr:** I *suspect* this can be solved by somehow telling the change detector that the parent will change as well, so how do I walk up the change-detection-tree? It may or may not be important that there is a `<router-outlet>` between the parent and the child.

**Full explanation, in case I have a completly wrong understanding**:
The code in question roughly looks like this: The `ChildComponent` has two subscriptions that need to be fulfilled and once they are ready the component is displayed and some view variables are reset to meaningful values.

```ts
this._routeParams.params.subscribe(params => {
    var pageId = params['pageId'];
    this._projectService.activeProject
        .subscribe(res => {
            // Project is loaded, display the correct page to edit
            this._project = res;
            this._page = this._project.getPageById(pageId);

            // The active page has changed: Reset render preview and sidebar
            this.doRenderPreview = false;
            // <<ERROR>> triggered by this line
            this._sidebarService.showSidebar(SidebarComponent.SIDEBAR_IDENTIFIER);
        });
})
```

The call to `SidebarService.showSidebar()` basically updates an `Observable` in this globally available `SidebarService` which is then used to actually render the sidebar in the `ParentComponent`.

```ts
// this.model is a BehaviourSubject
showSidebar(newType : string, param? : any) {
    if (!this.isKnownType(newType)) {
        throw new Error(`Unknown sidebar type: ${newType}`);
    }

    this._model.next({
        type : newType,
        param : param
    });
}
```

There is another observable that only propagates changes about the visibility state, this is important for components that need to know whether there is a sidebar but do not care about the specifics.

```ts
get isSidebarVisible() : Observable<boolean> {
    return (this._model.map(s => !!s));
}
```

In order to render the sidebar, the `ParentComponent` needs to update its layout, this is where the error occurs:

```html
<!-- Error: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true' -->
<div *ngIf="isSidebarVisible | async"
     class="sidebar">
  <sidebar-loader></sidebar-loader>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isSidebarVisible | async"
     class="sidebar-hack">
  <!-- Dirty hack to ensure the main content is not too wide -->
</div>
```

The `isSidebarVisible` property is simply a shortcut to the global service:

```ts
get isSidebarVisible() {
    return (this._sidebarService.isSidebarVisible);
}
```

I *suspect* that the problem is that a change in the `Editor` component results in a change it's parent component. But I do have similar code in other places, a key difference for this scenario *might* be that the child is loaded via a `<router-outlet>`?

**Edit**: The behaviour is the same when avoiding the `async` pipe in the view and instead "cache" `isSidebarVisible` in the parent and update it via a subscription: `this._sidebarService.isSidebarVisible.subscribe(v => this._sidebarVisible = v);`.

Answer (score 1):

To propagate changes up the tree you might want to use the EventEmitter, a guide here: https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2

However, i think you should maybe set up a subscribe to the observable in the global variable which sets `isSidebarVisible` to either true or false and set up `isSidebarVisible: boolean = false;` to be a simple boolean. Then once the sidebar should be visible, you just need to set this value to true.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I updated the post accordingly. Sadly pulling the subscription into the component didn't help, the error stays exactly the same. From what I understand, using a `EventEmitter` does not work across a `<router-outlet>`. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: it does work yes, we use it in work, however you may want to create a wrapper for it

Answer (score 1):

Solution that should work for you is that `ParentComponent` should notify change detection that changes happen. So you can

- Inject ChangeDetector to your component: 
  `constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}`
- Subscribe to changes of `_sidebarService.isSidebarVisible` and to update layout and mark component for change detection:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this._sidebarService.isSidebarVisible.subscribe((visibility) => {
      this.visibility = visibility; // application state changed
      this.cd.markForCheck(); // marks path
    })
}
```

Here are some more details: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: For a second this seemed like it would exactly be what I need, but for some reason the additional call to `markForCheck()` doesn't change anything about the error.